# How to override variables from nested packages in go language?

Tags: go

How do I override variables in go from  package ?

For example:

**file1.go**

```
package A

import "A/B"

var Arg1 = "Hello"
```

**file2.go**

```
package A/B

var Arg1 = "World"
```

How can I override arg1 in file1.go if arg1 exist in file2.go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this, where, for example, a specific location (USA), if present, overrides a general location (World)?

```
// file A/B.go

package B

var location = "USA"

func Location() string {
    return location
}

// file A.go

package A

import "A/B"

var location = "World"

func Location() string {
    loc := B.Location()
    if len(loc) == 0 {
        loc = location
    }
    return loc
}

// file main.go

package main

import (
    "A"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello,", A.Location())
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, USA
```

If not, please provide a better and specific example of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "overriding" in this case. (Also let me assume file1.go is 'package a' and file2.go is 'package b')

If you mean to access `Arg1`, defined in package "b" inside/from within package "a", then eg.:

```
// In package "a"
x = Arg1    // references a.Arg1
y = b.Arg1  // references b.Arg1
```

However, nothing resembling overriding happens here. In package "a" both a's `Arg1` and b's `Arg1` are accessible as different entities; the later via a mandatory qualifier 'b'.

Comment: I think the problem is that posts about overriding variable usually suggest `go build -ldflags "-X main.GitCommit=$GIT_COMMIT"` assuming that overriding variable is in main and don't know that someone wants to override variables in nested packages. That's why some can ask/google questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Packages are self-contained.
If package A doesn't export arg1 (lowercase)
it is not visible -- and thus not set-able --
for an other package B.

BTW: "package A/B" looks pretty strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it using a build flag :

```
go build -ldflags="-X 'package_path.variable_name=new_value'"
```

Couple of things to be aware of though :

*In order to use ldflags, the value you want to change **must exist** and be a package level variable of **type string**. This variable can be **either exported or unexported**. The value **cannot be a const** or have its value set by the result of a function call*

You'll find all the information needed in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-ldflags-to-set-version-information-for-go-applications) excellent post from DO team

Comment: for example, 
if you use `something.Something` and import it like `import "your_app/internal/nested/something"`,
you should add `-ldflags="-X your_app/internal/nested/something.Something=$COMPUTED_BY_BASH"`